# SGD data should be randomly selected or sequentially feed?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

When training neural network, is it better to randomly choose data for every batch or feed the data sequentially? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you feed the data randomly, there are fewer chances of overfitting than if you feed the data sequentially.

If the data is fed sequentially, then the network will not learn to generalize as the weights will be updated for that batch according to that same image again and again.

It is always recommended to feed the randomly.